# Error when calling 'get_environment_variable'

Tags: fortran, environment-variables, gfortran

An app is causing some I/O errors when trying to open some files. The app is pretty large with dozens of subroutines & modules and skipping one of them doesn't fix the problem because another one will cause a similar one. I took one of the subroutines, added some lines (for extra info), recompiled and rerun it. The results is that the environmental variables seem to be missing or fault. For example, when I try to get the current directory with `call get_environment_variable('PWD',pwd)` and print out the value of pwd (defined as `character(len=128)`), I'm getting the error `Fortran runtime error: End of record`. I also tried with cwd but same result. It seems like something in the code is altering these environmental variables or making them inaccessible, but I cannot put my fingers on what is it or how to pinpoint the original issue.

Comment: You forgot to tell us which OS and which version of gfortran.

Comment: It's Ubuntu20.04 and GCC12.1.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the value of PWD.   If it contains some odd control character or unprintable character, this might cause an EOR condition.

Comment: It's just `/home/ubuntu/scripts/WRF-4.4`

Comment: Thanks.  Have you tried compiling with debugging  options? If not, try '-fcheck=all'.  If you're stepping off the end of an array, you might be corrupting memory elsewhere.

Comment: Hi @steve. I've been tinkering around with the debug option and it seems that the problem is not directly related to I/O operations or the environmental variables per se. However, and this is what I find a bit weird, this is how it manifests. I guess that I'll erase the thread because it's probably not useful to other people.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with out-of-bound array accesses.  One accidentally stomps on memory and only finds out later in the code.  One then spend too much time on a snipe hunt.  If you're using gfortran, I recommend the following options whlie debugging: `-g -O -fmax-errors=1 -Werror -fcheck=all -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-conversion -Wno-integer-division`

Answer (score 2):

Memory corruption could cause unintended consequences anywhere in the code. It will be impossible to give a right answer unless you provide a "minimum reproducible example" of your problem.

Regarding your error message though: the compiler is telling you that the character variable you're reading `PWD` in is too short (could be easily hundreds of characters).

I suggest you first query the `LENGTH` of that character variable, then use an `allocatable` string to store it and use `STATUS` to check that everything went right

```
integer :: char_length,ierr
character(:), allocatable :: pwd

! Get string length of variable PWD
call get_environment_variable('PWD',length=char_length)

if (char_length<=0) stop 'environment does not contain PWD variable'

! Allocate dynamic string
allocate(character(len=char_length) :: pwd)

! Get its value
call get_environment_variable('PWD',value=pwd,status=ierr)

! Check success
select case (ierr)
   case (0); ! all right, do nothing
   case (1); stop 'PWD does not exist'
   case (2); stop 'this compiler does not support environment variables'
end select
```

Comment: `get_environment_variable` does not give an end-of-record condition if the (Fortran) character variable is too short for the value of the environment variable.

Comment: The code has literally tens of thousands of lines so I cannot provide a minimum reproducible example (and writing a little code doesn't produce any error). Hence, I'm trying to work my way back but, as you point out, other problems might cascade down and they're not easy to pinpoint.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684816/end-of-record-error-in-file-opening also suggests that the length of your character variable containing the path/file name is too short

Comment: also note that `PWD` may have trailing blanks, so the length of the character variable you need is not necessarily related to the length of your current directory name

Comment: The subdirectory name is not that long an doesn't have any special characters.

Comment: After farther testing, the error seems to have nothing to do with the length of the character variable but something else in the code is causing sort of a chain reaction.